# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Spatie\Ssr\Engines\V8::__construct()

Tags: php, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I want to use server side rendering for my vue app and I've found [this library](https://github.com/spatie/server-side-rendering)

I've followed a tutorial on how to setup my app to be able to use server side rendering but when I deploy it to the server and try to see the page I get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Spatie\Ssr\Engines\V8::__construct(), 0 passed
```

I have experience with php and this error normally is fixable by passing the required arguments to a class constructor.

**In this case, the library documentation didn't provide any documentation about `V8` class constructor.**

At the moment I have this code that is the same of the snippet provided into the github repo of the library

```
<?php 
require_once __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";

use Spatie\Ssr\Renderer;
use Spatie\Ssr\Engines\V8;

$engine = new V8();

$renderer = new Renderer($engine);

echo $renderer
    ->entry(__DIR__."/js/main.js")
    ->render();

?>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The error you're getting means that the V8 class needs an argument to be sent to his constructor.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @aynber 7.1 on shared hosting

Comment: @MichaelTétreault I know what the error means as I wrote into the question. The problem is that there is no documentation about the class and it's constructor.

Comment: I suggest you to contact them directly for that question:
https://github.com/spatie/server-side-rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to take a short look into their code. As it is open and you even liked to it. So it should not be that difficult.

According to their unit tests a V8 instance is constructed this way:

`$engine = new V8(new V8Js());`

look at https://github.com/spatie/server-side-rendering/blob/master/tests/Engines/V8Test.php

So the constructor in V8 class needs a V8Js object. The parameter is not optional as the code says:

```
    public function __construct(V8Js $v8)
    {
        $this->v8 = $v8;
    }
```

Found here: https://github.com/spatie/server-side-rendering/blob/master/src/Engines/V8.php

Interestingly, an issue on this topic has been closed. Perhaps it should be reopened with further details?
https://github.com/spatie/server-side-rendering/issues/32

Comment: I've seen the class code after that I get the error. Into the documentation they didn't talk about this dependency of the `V8` class constructor, anyway I will pass a V8Js instance to the class to try fixing the problem.

Comment: I think, they simply forgot to update their documentation after they made this change about 2,5 years ago: https://github.com/spatie/server-side-rendering/commit/ba2ffa9c377225260bb903f29174eeded3c15b76#diff-0199ff2f5e33e6b9baa97f1fd64d0514